# Is it okay to keep my hard-drive connected while shutting down my pc?

Tags: external-hard-drive, usb-flash-drive, desktop-computer

My question extends to other devices like flash-drives etc.

Should we remove devices before shutting down PC ?
(Or is there a risk of some fault)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You CAN keep your hard drive or other storage devices connected while your PC shuts down.

No risk of data loss. But if you initiate shutdown process in your OS, wait for it to completely shutdown and turn off and then remove your hard disk. Don't disconnect while the shutdown process is active. Let the cache be flushed correctly to hard disk, if there is one.

Comment: Or leave it "permanently" connected.  No need to remove it at all.  In that case, if it isn't a bootable device or one you normally want to boot from, make sure its boot order is after the internal hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep them connected, but if you unplug the hard drive during the shutdown process you may end up with data corruption. You can indeed keep it connected.

Comment: Please show more data to back your answer, do operating systems or any other part of a computer tend to do this?

Answer (score 0):

But how to fix that, if you end up corrupting your external hard drive while disconnecting it during shutdown?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hey Melonade!, I see this is your first time here, please take your time and go through the process of writing a question on this platform, including checking for a duplicate for what you are trying to ask, as this is a question on it's own.